# Email if a cron job succeeds on Cronitor

Tags: cron, email-notifications

Is it possible to add a setting on Cronitor that sends an email once a cron job succeeds. Right now I only get email if a cron job fails.

This is what i have at the moment :

```
Alert preferences   Failure tolerance    Duration alerts

Alert notes

(X) Send alerts any time there is a problem
()  Only send alerts if my job has consistently not run when expected...
```

I tried to email/contact support but now answer from Cronitor yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the creators of Cronitor. I'm really sorry we somehow missed your support inquiry.

The answer is that, yes, this is possible but you cannot set this up without an API call. After the initial setup is complete (and the new alert rule is added) you can continue managing the monitor from the dashboard.

If you email support@cronitor.io again with specifics I can help you with adding this rule via the API.

Comment: Thanks Shane, ill email you directly. I tired to call customer support and email but no answer back